# LuaTeX script that copies file, but inserts extra code if asked to

Tags: luatex

I am aware of the many crazy callbacks in LuaTeX, but can they be used to solve the following problem?

I would like a LuaLaTeX script that works the following way. Suppose my LaTeX document is called `myfile.tex`. Then the script should do the following:

1. The script creates a new file `myfile_new.tex` (this is easy, of course, and can be done using classical TeX.)
2. While the document `myfile.tex` is being compiled, each line of this file is being copied to the file `myfile_new.tex`, so it becomes a copy of `myfile.tex` – but there is a twist:
3. I want a TeX command `\writetonewfile`, taking one argument, which writes that argument to the file `myfile_new.tex` in the exact position where the command was found.

Let us see an example: Suppose this is my file `myfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{ ... } % insert some Lua code

\newcommand\writetonewfile[1]{ ... } % insert appropriate Lua code

\newcommand\foo{This is foo.\writetonewfile{This was foo.}}

\newcommand\foobar[1]{This is foobar.\writetonewfile{This was #1.}}

\begin{document}

Hello World. \writetonewfile{And A Happy New Year.}

\foo

\foobar{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

After compiling this with LuaLaTeX, I would like `myfile_new.tex` to contain the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{ ... } % insert some Lua code

\newcommand\writetonewfile[1]{ ... } % insert appropriate Lua code

\newcommand\foo{This is foo.\writetonewfile{This was foo.}}

\newcommand\foobar[1]{This is foobar.\writetonewfile{This was #1.}}

\begin{document}

Hello world. \writetonewfile{And A Happy New Year.}And A Happy New Year.

\fooThis was foo.

\foobar{Hello World}This was Hello World.

\end{document}
```

(Of course, if I actually compile this document, it will complain that `\fooThis` was never `\def`’ed, but you see the idea.)

A Lua script that just searches and replaces in the file will not suffice: What I want is an actual LaTeX command `\writetonewfile`. In particular, if I use `expl3` and redefine the command as `\mydoc_write_to_new_file:n`, I should be able to define commands like `\mydoc_write_to_new_file:x` etc. and expand the code before it gets written to the new file.

Is this possible?

Comment: I guess you wouldn't be happy if the new text is always added at the end of the line where the command is encountered, would you?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger No, it does not quite solve the issue, unfortunately. :-( It is supposed to be part of a “de-macro” script that removes a specific collection of commands from a document, to make it ready for publication. Therefore, it’s quite important that it appears right after the commands it is supposed to replace.

Comment: Similar to most other data about the input stack, `iloc`, the location in the current line, is not exposed to Lua directly. Your best bet is probably to set `\contextlines` sufficiently big and then call `tex.show_context()`. If the remaining part of your line is not too long(where the meaning of "too long" depends on error_line and half_error_line), you should be able to determine your current location from that.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger But `show_context` needs an error to be produced and TeX will terminate after 100 errors, so this might not be so useful.  What is really needed is a callback that triggers when a macro is expanded or when a token is turned into a node or somewhere in that chain.  Currently there is a big void between `process_input_buffer` and `hyphenate`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I had a look at the source and the `cur_input` structure is defined as `extern` in `tex/inputstack.h` so you can access it using the FFI.

Comment: @HenriMenke About `show_context`: It is typically used in connection with errors, but that's not really a requirement. You *can* call `show_context` whenever you want to get the current context without triggering any errors.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger FFI works, but I have no idea why `iloc` is 15 at the start of the line. http://dpaste.com/7V9HMP4SX (expires in 10 days)

Comment: @HenriMenke `iloc` does not directly describe the offset in the current line, but the position in a buffer which potentially has other content before the current line. To get the current column, take `iloc-istart` (+1 if you prefer 1-based counting) (`istart` stands for the current `start_field`)

Comment: @Gaussler An idea is to define `\writetonewfile` in a way that it saves its arguments to a dedicated file. Then, use [TeXSoup](https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup) to parse your TeX document and replace each `\writetonewfile` with contents saved in the file.